# Checking date ECW orthophoto taken?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, metadata, ecw

I've have several orthophotos stored in an [ECW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECW_(file_format)) (Enhanced Compression Wavelet) file format. For most of them the exact acquisition date is referred in the file name - e.g. "Paris_24_12_2011". But for some of them this information is lacking. I'm currently using ArcGIS 10.3.

Is there a way to check when the orthophoto was taken? maybe some metadata?
If so, how can I watch this data?

1. I've tried to look it up and found this [page](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_ecw.html) of ECW file specification including metadata for GDAL use. I'm not familiar with GDAL so I left it aside for the moment.
2. I've downloaded [erdas er viewer 2014](http://download.intergraph.com/downloads/erdas-er-viewer-2014-v14.01), thought it might give me some metadata access. It didn't.

Is there any simple, free-to-use way that can help me find the date of the orthophoto?

Answer (score 1):

The metadata embedded in the ECW header file doesn't include the date taken as far as I know. To view most of the metadata without an erdas licence, you can open the raster in QGIS and look at the metadata section in the layer properties. It will tell you the compression target rate, ECW version, number of bands, dimensions, origin (top right corner), pixel size, cell type, spatial reference.